# Are these viral memes?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-request, phrase-request

These days I see many people are tweeting or re-tweeting or liking tweets like this:

[image]

Some instances are the follows:

1. https://twitter.com/patrickmineault/status/1388224997622231040
2. https://twitter.com/zacharynado/status/1388298365390229505
3. https://twitter.com/rosorg/status/1388280173036904449

My questions are these two:

1. Are they viral memes? Or viral/sarcasmic templates? I think it would be something like "黑话" in Chinese and wonder if they are argots(the translation of "黑话")?
2. What is such a phenomenon called?

Comment: Original source is xkcd: https://xkcd.com/2456/

Comment: It's a humorous drawing, or to be specific, a panel from a webcomic. They're not memes. They're not templates. It's just sarcastic work humor.

Comment: ANYTHING that mutates a certain thought, ANY thought through any kind of culture is a meme by the original meaning of the word. so sorry, but yes, it is a webcomic, but it is ALSO a meme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question!

First, we should separate the two elements of the phrase: "viral" and "meme." *Virality* is a term developed in the Internet era to describe a specific thing that spreads very wide very quickly. You might encounter a viral meme, or a viral meme template, or a viral video, or you might even say a specific tweet has "gone viral." The term is probably overused in my opinion, but I don't think there's any quantitative bar that separates "viral" from "non-viral;" it's fluid. In this case, with re-tweet numbers in the middling-to-low tens, I would not call these edits "viral" (at least not yet).

This brings me to the second part of the term, "meme." [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meme#English) points out that it is a coined term which originated with Richard Dawkins and originally meant "a unit of cultural information." In the Internet era, memes have gone through several generations or iterations, including:

- [LOLcats](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/lolcats)
- [image macros](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/image-macros), reaction images or GIFs, usually in the classic "top text"/"bottom text" format
- ["deep fried" memes](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/deep-fried-memes), which may or may not make any sense (which is part of the meme)
- [exploitables](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/exploitables), where a part of the image (often the text) is edited to describe a new situation based on or using the original image

I would say that the images people are posting are examples of **exploitables**. They are using the original format and context, and editing it to show examples of a different area and context.

---

As a side note, although the service is called "Twitter," the things people post are called "tweets" and the verb is "to tweet"/"tweeting." A "twit" is a rude person.

Comment: I see that someone is calling this a meme: https://twitter.com/AndrewBarnas/status/1388161745684996098

Comment: an exploitable is a form of meme

Comment: They are compilations of "typical" papers and memes as written [here](https://newsletter.ruder.io/issues/eacl-iclr-naacl-papers-round-up-research-reality-checks-ml-on-code-592784).